# Border radius and background clip not working as expected on pseudo element

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a button that has many layers - consequently I'm having to make use of pseudo elements.

To clarify, my button is actually an anchor `<a>`.

I've run into an issue with one of the pseudo elements. I'm trying to give it a background while retaining a touchable target outside of the background. In order to do this, I've applied a background-clip over the content.

Everything works apart from the corners, which are applied but just not the shape I was expecting.

Button 2 is the design I'm trying to crack - by ensuring the pseudo perfectly overlays the element.

**I now think I know what is happening but don't know why and how to fix it.
The padding is 6px deep, the border radius 10px. The radius is being calculated as 4px deep and 10px wide.**

Any advice appreciated.

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

a, a::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  min-width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

a::before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 6px 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.button2::before, .button2a::before {
  background-clip: content-box;
}

.button2a {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.button2a::before {
  background-color: blue;
}

.button3::before {
  background-clip: content-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>This is a button with no background-clip - border-radius applied as expected<p>
  <p><a class="button1">button 1</a></p>
</div>
<div>
<p>This has same border-radius as above, but background-clip applied on content - overlay doesn't completely disappear - leaves odd shapes at corners as can be seen on blue button. I was expecting 10px corners to mirror center</p>
  <p><a class="button2">button 2</a><a class="button2a">button 2</a></p>
</div>
<div>
<p>This has same background-clip applied but uses a percentage for border-radius - seems to work as expected</p>
  <p><a class="button3">button 3</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to create a button that has many layers

What about doing things differently and instead of using pseudo element you can rely on multiple background to have multiple layers:

```css
a.button1 {
  background: 
   linear-gradient(to right,transparent 50%,blue 0),
   linear-gradient(to bottom,orange 50%,transparent 0),
   red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a class="button1">button 1</a>
```